# Deploy on external Tomcat and SAP Java Connector

Tags: tomcat, deployment, external, jco

I deploy my JSF project with ant on a VM with SAP but got the Exception when I try to connect:

> JCO.nativeInit(): Could not initialize dynamic link library sapjcorfc [Native Library C:\WINDOWS\system32\sapjcorfc.dll already loaded in another classloader].

I'll remove my JCo Jar from the WEB-INF folder and add it in the tomcat lib folder. But how I can add the Jar in my Eclipse when the Jar file is on the external tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the jar to a local directory outside of your project, and add it to the classpath. this should allows you to compile, but will not transport the jar to the external tomcat, where it will be acessible to your app since its in the lib/ext folder.